# CALayer rendering caused memory leak on new MacBook Pro with OSX 10.7.4

Tags: xcode, macos, memory-leaks, calayer, xcode-instruments

While developing Mac OSX application using CALayer rendering, we have found the Apple official sample code 'CALayerEssentials' may cause memory leak on new MacBook Pro (Mid 2012 15' Retina) with OSX 10.7.4.

Memory leak general description:

1. Running 'CALayerEssentials' project with Xcode; (You can find this project under Xcode Organizer -> OS X 10.7 Core Library -> Graphics & Animation -> Animation -> CALayerEssentials)
2. Open Instruments Leaks template, and attach to CALayerEssentials process id;
3. Start record, and the Leaks will indicate there is memory leak happens about every 10 seconds;
4. In Leaks Object panel, there is an item 'Malloc 48 Bytes' with increasing counts and memory size;
5. After about 15 mins, leak size will increase to about 2.48 MB;
6. After about 78 mins, leak size will increase to about 23.54 MB;
7. By checking leak addresses in vmmap result address region, there indicates all addresses have something to do with QuartzCore_0x6bb2a800 like following line:

MALLOC_OTHER           086af000-086d1000 [  136K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  QuartzCore_0x6bb2a800

Here's the screen shot of running CALayerEssentials and monitoring its memory leaks:
http://smartsweetie.com/uploads/screenshot1.png

Here's the memory leak Machines system configuration:

- Machine: MacBook Pro (Mid 2012, 15' Retina)
- Processor: 2.3 GHz Intel
- Core i7 Memory: 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB
- Software: Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4 (11E2620)

However, running the same CALayerEssentials on other machines won't have CALayer memory leak issue.

- Machine: MacBook Pro (Late 2011, 15')
- Processor: 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7
- Memory: 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
- Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6750M 512 MB
- Software: Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4 (11E53)

Is there any known issue on CALayer memory leak on new MacBook Pro with OS X 10.7.4?
Or any advice to further investigate this issue?